# Which process/task is responsible for data blocks replication?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Which software process in Hadoop is responsible for replicating the data blocks across different datanodes with a particular replication factor?

Answer (score 0):

"The NameNode makes all decisions regarding replication of blocks. It periodically receives a Heartbeat and a Blockreport"
Here is a breakdown of HDFS architecture and design: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/hdfs_design.html#Data+Replication, try looking at the value of the dfs.block.replicator.classname settings in hdfs-site.xml to see what The name of the class which specifies how to place blocks in HDFS